# Максимум 2 заглавных в строке

Tags: регулярные-выражения

появилась такая проблема, которую я конечно же не могу решить, поскольку совершенно не знаю регулярных выражений, поскольку они редко пригождаются.
К сути дела. На вход получаю строку, которая должна содержать максимум 2 заглавных буквы в строке. Причём, только на латинице или кириллице. Строка может либо содержать 0 таких букв, либо 1, либо 2. Эти буквы могут идти подряд, либо могут располагаться в разных местах слова или двух слов строки (к примеру). Прошу помощи, буду невероятно благодарен.

Comment: Я думаю намного проще будет пробежать по строке такой регуляркой `/[A-Z]/g` и если вхождений больше чем 2- генерировать ошибку.

Comment: `^(?:[^A-ZА-ЯЁ]*[A-ZА-ЯЁ]){2}[^A-ZА-ЯЁ]*$`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew У вас регулярка с 0-1 строчной буквой не проходит. https://regex101.com/r/2FAd3I/1
Замените {2} на {0, 2}

Comment: Да, `^(?:[^A-ZА-ЯЁ]*[A-ZА-ЯЁ]){0,2}[^A-ZА-ЯЁ]*$` должна подойти.

Comment: Спасибо, то, что нужно!

Comment: @AlexeyS. отметьте пожалуйста галочкой ответ Виктора.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать

```
^(?:[^A-ZА-ЯЁ]*[A-ZА-ЯЁ]){0,2}[^A-ZА-ЯЁ]*$
```

См. [демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/vmJaDk/1)

**Подробности**

- `^` - начало строки
- `(?:[^A-ZА-ЯЁ]*[A-ZА-ЯЁ]){0,2}` - 0, 1 или 2 последовательности двух шаблонов

  - `[^A-ZА-ЯЁ]*` - 0 и более символов, отличных от заглавных английских и русских букв
  - `[A-ZА-ЯЁ]` - одна заглавная английская или русская буква
- `[^A-ZА-ЯЁ]*` - 0 и более символов, отличных от заглавных английских и русских букв
- `$` - конец строки.

**ВНИМАНИЕ**: В некоторых средах (напр. Powershell) или приложениях (напр. SublimeText, Notepad++) на работу данной регулярки может повлиять регистронезависимый режим. В таких случаях часто помогает задание регистрозависимого поиска с помощью модификатора `(?-i)`:

```
(?-i)^(?:[^A-ZА-ЯЁ]*[A-ZА-ЯЁ]){0,2}[^A-ZА-ЯЁ]*$
```

Также следите, чтобы случайно не указать модификатор `i` (`/.../i`).